# How to enable the functioanality of Intellij to show errors in vertical scroll bar

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a problem with Intellij that cannot show the errors in vertical scroll bar while there are errors in editor. For better understanding the question, please see the picture bellow:
[image]

As the picture above, it shows the warning and also shows spelling errors etc..., but don't show the error.
How to enable this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I solved like this: `Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General`

**Note:** In the new version of the Intellij

```
Settings -> Editor -> Colors Scheme -> General
```

[image]